# Python: Regex matches in Windows but not in Linux 4.4.59+

Tags: regex, linux, windows, macos, python-2.7

I have this code, trying to replace curly quotes with straight quotes

```
        quoteChars = [u'\u2018', u'\u2019']
        pattern = u'({0})'.format('|'.join(quoteChars))
        matched = re.search(pattern, myString)  # match against whole string
        if matched:
            self.log('SELF:: Search Query:: Replacing characters in string. Found one of these {0}'.format(pattern))
            myString = re.sub(pattern, "'", myString)
            self.log('SELF:: Amended Search Query [{0}]'.format(myString))
        else:
            self.log('SELF:: Search Query:: String has none of these {0}'.format(pattern))
```

I set the variable myString to the following `(‘Pop‑Up’ Edition)` 
In windows it correctly detects that there are curly apostrophe's but when I try it on a Mac whic reports its OS as Linux 4.4.59+ it does not match the pattern..

Do I have to set the regex pattern differently on Linux? And what are the rules? in relation to curly apostrophes both single and double, opening or closing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex escapes:

```
quoteChars = [r'\u2018', r'\u2019']
pattern = '|'.join(quoteChars)
```

Then

```
myString = re.sub(pattern, "'", myString)
```

Comment: This didn't work it searched for '\u2018' as the 6 characters rather than what unicode character it was meant to be....

Comment: @JasonHudson However, these characters are [removed](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolauwNL8k1TkjsahYwVYhukg9ptTIwNBCXUcByrRUj@UqSCwpSS3KAypQr1HXy8rPzNNAaNPkKijKzCvRKErVKy5N0oCq1VFQB5qh/qhhRklqRcmjhpnqmppc//8DAA).

Comment: It didn't work on windows... I will ask my friend who is on Linux to test... My previous code worked in Windows... Why wouldn't it work in Linux?

Comment: @JasonHudson If you work with Python 2.x, my solution still works, see https://ideone.com/HPrMaA. This is in Linux .

Comment: I will try the new code... I never knew one could combine u and r ...

Comment: Do you have a reason why my original code worked in Windows but not in Linux?

Comment: @JasonHudson If you work in Python 2.x, the Windows build as a "narrow" build that did not work well with non-ASCII characters. Linux builds were "wide" build that worked with these characters. Python3 builds are all "wide", all strings support Unicode by default.